# LESS/ CSS ： Writing a static text on image

Tags: css, less, styling

I have following image as following,

[image]

How can i write text on image above and achieve the outcome as the following?

Comment: have you try something? you can use position absolute for text or use an image as background.

Comment: text is behind of my image because my image also position absolute.

Comment: can you share some code please? you have to play with z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper #id1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.wrapper #id2 {
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.wrapper #id3 {
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper #id4 {
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper #id5 {
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.wrapper #id6 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label id="id1">Text Left!</label>
  <label id="id2">Text Right!</label>
  <label id="id3">Text Bottom Left!</label>
  <label id="id4">Text Bottom Right!</label>
  <label id="id5">Text Rotate Right!</label>
  <label id="id6">Text Rotate Left!</label>
  <img src="https://keyassets.timeincuk.net/inspirewp/live/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2015/07/Depth-of-field-landscape.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have HTML like:

```
<div class="container">
  <img />
  <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

something like this would work (you'll have to fiddle the values obviously):

```
.container {
  position: relative; 

  img{ z-index: 1; // img styles here }
  p { position: absolute; left: 0.5rem; top: 0.5rem; z-index: 3; transform: rotate(90deg) }

}
```

**Step by step:**

- Position the text absolutely
- Rotate it 90 degrees
- Set a Z-index higher than the image
- Position the text correctly on the image
- Profit ...